# Spring Boot execute a method at a specific time

Tags: spring-boot, runtime, scheduled-tasks

Suppose I have the following method head in a service:

```
public void sentMail(LocalDateTime date, User user);
```

I want that when running this method an email is sent to this user etc. Sending an email is no problem, but I don't know how to make it so that this email can be sent exactly at this time.

I noticed that you can trigger method in a certain interval, but this doesn't look like "THE" solutions to me.

Comment: Do you want the interval to be configurarable e.g. specify the exact time to run the task - which will vary from time to time?

Comment: Also my suggestion would be to create a @Schedule that runs every odd intervals to look for mails to send. It should only send those that fall within the time to be sent.